# Excel: enter value of column C into the middle of value of column B

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

If my L8 cell has TEST and my L9 has

```
ABCDEFG</div>RED
```

and I am trying to get

```
ABCDEFGTEST</div>RED
```

as a result I am using:

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(L9,SEARCH("G</div>",L9))&L8&RIGHT(L9,SEARCH("</div>",L9)))
```

But my actual result looks like:

```
ABCDEFGTEST/div>RED
```

How do i fix this? so, I dont lose the < on my end dig tag?

Edit: rewrote with simplified example to hopefully be more clear

Edit2: concatenate example

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, try adding some screenshot and before and after result you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula to get `ABCDEFGTEST</div>RED`

`=REPLACE(L9,FIND("<",L9),0,L8)`

Comment: Wait? I just edited, What will this do to my current formula?

Comment: Awesome, I think this will solve my problem. Now i just need to try it on the real data.

Answer (score 0):

combine `Concatenate` with the `Left`, `Mid`, `Right` (to get a partial string) and the `Find` and `Len` (to see where this "middle" is either by finding a specific string or a location) functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is; I agree with @Mowgli.

Having said that, I'm going to take a stab.

If you're trying to insert column C in the middle of column B, I would move the URL & img to separate columns (for the same of argument, let's make them K & L(as K_B states, you can use FIND to do this.)

Then I'd make column Z1 = "&C1&"

Comment: Ya I don't think I can separate them into different columns and I am struggling to use the Left,Search,Find,Right commands because both cell values are large strings of HTML

Comment: Maybe I can separate them temporarily, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Column B
ABC
Column C
123

Formula
=LEFT(B3,2)&C3&RIGHT(B3,1)